# Changes in depended lib does not affect application after migrating to Angular 17

Tags: angular, npm

In an Angular project while developing/debugging I'm linking a lib (that is also developed by me) with `npm link`. First I go to `dist/my-lib` folder in workspace with that lib and do `npm link`, then I go to project and do `npm link @my-scope/my-lib`, after that `node_modules/@my-scope/my-lib` becomes a symlink to a `dist/my-lib` folder of lib workspace.

The problem is that after changing something in lib I do not see that changes in application.

In dev console I see

> [webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling...
> [webpack-dev-server] Nothing changed.

still contents of `node_modules/@my-scope/my-lib` folder (e.g. `index.ts` is updated). What can cause such an issue?

Both application and link have `cli.cache.enabled` set to `false`.

Before migrating to Angular 17 I was using Angular 15 and I've not experienced problems like that.

**UPD.** I've tried removing `.angular` and doing `npm cache clean --force`. That has no effect.

Comment: you can try this, Delete `.angular` folder in your project directory, `npm cache clean --force`. then `ng serve` see if it works or not.

Comment: I believe i have the same issue. I didn't have problem with link before migrating to angular 17. Since then, if i use npm link then make a change in my library, my browser will detect the change and i'll get the following messages in the console:
[webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling...
[webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling...
[webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling...
[webpack-dev-server] Nothing changed.
[webpack-dev-server] Nothing changed.
[webpack-dev-server] Nothing changed.

The browser page itself will not reload (as "nothing changed").

Answer (score 1):

The `node_modules` folder is not watched by default by the build systems.

Locally instead of `npm link` a mock npm server can be also used. Like [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/).

If you want to build applications like this consider using a monorepo. [Nx](https://nx.dev) has great tools to build libraries and applications side-by-side.

Comment: I had no issues with not updating app after `npm link` and lib rebuild in Angular 15, so I assume it's an issue of Angular version (Angular 17 uses another builder)

Comment: It depends on your configuration you can opt-in for esbuild.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is convert to a [workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces), this will allow you to not have to use `npm link` at all. However, you do have to convert to a monorepo. Your workspace would then be setup like this:

- You will have 3 `package.json` files (or more if you add more libraries).
- Your root will have a list of the workspaces.
- Your lib will have the lib name (example: `@scope/lib`).
- Your app will have an app name (example: `my-app`).

**Note:** You can organize this anyway you want, I just put them all in `projects` folder for simplicity.

```
- root
  - projects
    - app
      - package.json
    - lib
      - package.json
  - package.json
```

Next is to add the items to your root `package.json` in the `workspaces` property. This is an array with relative paths to each project (lib(s) and app(s)).

You can add add `dependencies` and `devDependencies` if you want. These will be shared across all libs and projects. (However, if you release to npm they might break if you put them in this file.

**Note:** I also added example scripts, that use the `-w` to reference which project to execute the command in.

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "workspaces": [
    "projects/app",
    "projects/lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve -w app",
    "build:lib": "npm run build -w lib"
  }
}
```

Next you create the `package.json` the same way you would for any other library or application.

For the library:

```json
{
  "name": "@scope/lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "... build command ..."
  }
}
```

For the application:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@scope/lib": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "... serve command ..."
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is run `npm install`, and it will install it and should keep watch on it.

Once install is complete, you could see up to 3 `node_modules` folders. The root one will have everything that works with all 3 `package.json` files. The other `node_modules` folders will be in each project, these are modules that don't work in the other 2 projects/`package.json`.

**Note:** I usually try to get everything to match so I only have one `node_modules` folder in the root of the project. This is done by having the same semantic version numbers on dependencies in all the projects.